# 404 error while moving wordpress site from local to live?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to move my WordPress site from local to live.  In my case homepage is working fine, but while migrating to next page or other menus it shows 404 error.  I have changed my .hdaccess file and permalink settings. But it is not working.  can anyone give a clear solution to this problem?

My existing .hdaccess file is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bookExperts/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /bookExperts/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have changed my .hdaccess as given below

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Comment: did you import database from local server to online server ?

Comment: Yes.... I have imported the database

Comment: so check table `wp_options` and check `option_name` siteurl.when you installed wordpress in local server it's taken the config of local server and when you upload site online you need new config matching with new server. So importing database is not good idea

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to table `wp_options` and change `site_url` and `home` with your new domain name.

after this go to `sql` tab in phpmyadmin and run below code

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '{old_domain}', '{new_domain}');
```

this will fix broken links & images.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

settings > permanent links > save changes

it's all

Before migrating you must have changed the url:

settings > WordPress address (URL) / Site address (URL)